# Extracting attachments from two rich text fields in a document

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I am extracting attachments in a document to user's local machine using LotusScript. The document has two rich text fields `Body1` and `Body2` and many a times only one of them has an attachment in it. I am using the below code snippet:

```
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim richTextItem As NotesRichTextItem
.....
.....
If doc.Hasembedded Then
    Set richTextItem = doc.Getfirstitem("Body1")
    ForAll o In richTextItem.Embeddedobjects
        Call o.ExtractFile(dirName + "\" + o.Name)
    End ForAll

    Set richTextItem = doc.Getfirstitem("Body2")
    ForAll o In richTextItem.Embeddedobjects
        Call o.ExtractFile(dirName + "\" + o.Name)
    End ForAll
End If
```

The problem is that if `Body1` does not have attachment in it and `Body2` does then the above code throws error of `Type mismatch` on statement `ForAll o In richTextItem.Embeddedobjects` and vice versa as there are no embedded objects in that rich text item. Also `doc.Embeddedobjects` does not work because attachments are present inside rich text items. And the `NotesRichTextItem` class does not have `Hasembedded` property which can be used to check presence of attachments in it.

What would be a way out of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Dim doc As NotesDocument
.....
.....
If doc.Hasembedded Then
    Set richTextItem = doc.Getfirstitem("Body1")
    Set rtnav = richTextItem.CreateNavigator

    If rtnav.FindFirstElement(RTELEM_TYPE_FILEATTACHMENT) Then
        Do
            Set att = rtnav.GetElement()
            filepath$ = dirName + "\" + att.Source
            Call att.ExtractFile(filepath$)      
        Loop While rtnav.FindNextElement()
    End If

    Set richTextItem = doc.Getfirstitem("Body2")
    Set rtnav = richTextItem.CreateNavigator

    If rtnav.FindFirstElement(RTELEM_TYPE_FILEATTACHMENT) Then
        Do
            Set att = rtnav.GetElement()
            filepath$ = dirName + "\" + att.Source
            Call att.ExtractFile(filepath$)      
        Loop While rtnav.FindNextElement()
    End If
End If
```

You may also want to extract the redundant logic into a subroutine.

Comment: Thanks Ken! I should probably start looking at the `NotesRichTextXXXXX` classes in more details I guess :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a short code if you want extract **all** attachments of a document no matter where they are stored:

```
Dim vAttachmentList As Variant
vAttachmentList = Evaluate("@AttachmentNames", doc)
If vAttachmentList(0) <> "" then
    ForAll sAttachmentName In vAttachmentList
        Call doc.Getattachment(sAttachmentName).ExtractFile(dirName + "\" + sAttachmentName)
    End ForAll
End if
```

Comment: This was my original code. But some my file names contain foreign characters (to be precise Chinese) so the variable `sAttachmentName` would not properly be able store them and eventually throwing error on `ExtractFile` function. But thanks for the code. It would be helpful to someone else hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

*Updated answer*

Instead of accessing the `EmbeddedObjects` property directly in the `forall`, assign it to a `variant` and check it first, using the `TypeName` function to make sure that the returned value was really an array of `NotesEmbeddedObject` objects, like this:

```
dim objectArray as variant
If doc.Hasembedded Then
    Set richTextItem = doc.Getfirstitem("Body1")
    Set objectArray = richTextItem.Embeddedobjects
    If TypeName(objectArray) = "NOTESEMBEDDEDOBJECT( )" Then
        ForAll o In objectArray
            Call o.ExtractFile(dirName + "\" + o.Name)
        End ForAll
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Sorry the code snippet throws the same error of `Type mismatch`.

Comment: Hmmm... In Java I've used this:  theObjects = rtBody.getEmbeddedObjects(); if ( (theObjects != null) && (!theObjects.isEmpty()) ) { for (Iterator iter = theObjects.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) { ... etc.  So I know I've got the right idea here, but not the right syntax, I guess.  Looking to see if I've got any equivalent LotusScript code.

Comment: Aha!  I found a LotusScript construct in some production code, so I know it's been pretty well tested.  It's not just testing for Nothing or using the DataType function (although I believe the latter would work).  It's using the TypeName function.  Updating my answer, for the record...

Comment: You code needs correction. It should be `If TypeName(objectArray) = "NOTESEMBEDDEDOBJECT( )" Then`. I replaced **`<>`** with **`=`**. And the code works perfectly. Also if you could remove the old code that would be better as it could confuse others. Thanks :)

Comment: I made the correction.  Thanks for pointing it out.  And I've deleted the code that didn't work.  (I do like preserving things for the record though, even my mistakes.  But you're right that it could confuse people.