# Is it possible to extract an attachment in a document in IBM Domino Notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, domino-designer-eclipse

Is it possible to extract an attachment in a document in IBM Domino Notes. I want to effectively run a script that will extract certain attachments in certain documents. I literally have no idea where to start :'(

Answer (score 5):

If you literally have no idea where to start, here's a rule of thumb: Start with Google instead of StackOverflow.

Search string: lotus notes attachments example script

Hit #1 refers to LCLSX.

Ignore that.

Hit #2 is an IBM help page [Working with attachments and embedded objects in LotusScript® classes](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_WORKING_WITH_EMBEDDED_OBJECTS_LOTUSSCRIPT.html)

Okay, that looks promising. It brings up a lot of info, but it's isolated reference info, not tutorial. But look! Down at the bottom of the page! There's a link labeled [Examples: Working with attachments and embedded objects in LotusScript® classes](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_EXAMPLE_WORKING_WITH_EMBEDDED_OBJECTS_LOTUSSCRIPT.html).

That's pretty much exactly what you need. That's literally where to start.

Answer (score 4):

My general advice:
open [IBM Domino Designer Documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/search/attachment?scope=SSVRGU_9.0.1) and search for a topic you are interested in.

Enter "attachment" into search field in this case and you will get a list of hits.
The seven's entry shows "[ExtractFile (NotesEmbeddedObject - LotusScript)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_EXTRACTFILE_METHOD.html)".
You'll find the description how to extract an attachment including an example in this document.

Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16720956/2065611) on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do that. I will describe a simple one.

Assume `currentDoc` is current document (`NotesDocument` instance). And assume there's only one attachment to this document.

```
Dim commandResult As Variant
Dim attachedFileName As String

commandResult = Evaluate({@AttachmentNames}, currentDoc) 'getting attachment names
attachedFileName = commandResult(0) 'getting the first value from the list of attached names

if attachedFileName = "" then
   MsgBox "There's no attached file in this document", 64, "Note"
   Exit Sub
End If

Set attachedFileObject = currentDoc.Getattachment(attachedFileName) 'getting object with attached file
Call attachedFileObject.ExtractFile( {C:\Temp\} + attachedFileName) 'extracting file to the C:\Temp folder
```

In case you want to detach all files iterate over `commandResult` that will contain names of all attached files.